# Netbeans Maven Web Project will not deploy

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, glassfish

I had a perfect running web application that I built using Glassfish as Application Server, until i re-named of the application from pcms to hims. Now it refuses to deploy.
I have been getting the following errors from Glassfish Server all night:

```
     [2014-09-29T07:41:03.719-0500] [glassfish 4.0] [SEVERE] [NCLS-CORE-00026] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=31 _ThreadName=admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1411994463719] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception during lifecycle processing
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Error starting resources in context /hims with Exception message: Document base {0} does not exist or is not a readable directory
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:291)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:352)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:497)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:527)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:523)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:522)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:546)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1423)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1500(CommandRunnerImpl.java:108)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1762)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1674)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandler.service(StaticHttpHandler.java:297)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:246)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.portunif.PUFilter.handleRead(PUFilter.java:231)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.portunif.PUFilter.handleRead(PUFilter.java:231)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
]]

[2014-09-29T07:41:03.720-0500] [glassfish 4.0] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=31 _ThreadName=admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1411994463720] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception while loading the app]]

[2014-09-29T07:41:03.741-0500] [glassfish 4.0] [SEVERE] [AS-WEB-GLUE-00192] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=31 _ThreadName=admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1411994463741] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Undeployment failed for context /hims]]

[2014-09-29T07:41:03.762-0500] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [org.eclipse.persistence.session.file:/home/ryan/Downloads/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/hims-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes/_com.jcf_hims_war_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU.connection] [tid: _ThreadID=955 _ThreadName=pool-56-thread-1] [timeMillis: 1411994463762] [levelValue: 800] [[
  file:/home/ryan/Downloads/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/hims-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes/_com.jcf_hims_war_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU logout successful]]

[2014-09-29T07:41:03.772-0500] [glassfish 4.0] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=31 _ThreadName=admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1411994463772] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Error starting resources in context /hims with Exception message: Document base {0} does not exist or is not a readable directory]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Renaming a project shouldn't cause problems assuming that you used the NetBeans Rename functionality and renamed project or folder or both.

It may be that NetBeans got confused somehow and you need to `Clean & Build` your project before deploying it again. Right-click your NetBeans project and click `Clean & Build` or use the corresponding button.

Another cause of the problem may be some reference to the old project name in one or more of the project files (e.g. `context.xml`). If you are not sure about that you can do a text search through the whole project: Select your project and press <kbd>Strg</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.